# equivalent to jquery object .get() method

Tags: jquery

This question might sound dumb, but is there an equivalent to the JQuery object method
`JQueryObjectArray.get('index')`
that takes a selector as parameter ? I've been looking for a couple hours now with no success.

```
<div>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li>...</li>
            <li>...</li>
            <li>...</li>
            <li>...</li>
            <li>...</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

var list = $('selector'); //selection is an array of JQuery objects.
/* the selector is complex and large (this is a sample), I use a variable to make the code cleaner */
...
list.get(':hover').val(function() {...});
```

*Important note:*
I'm talking about the JQuery **object** `.get()` method, not the JQuery function.

Here is the JQuery manual about `.get()` : https://api.jquery.com/get/

The solution I found (but I don't like it) :

```
list.parent().children(':hover').val(function() {...});
```

Comment: doesn't `$('.class').find(':hover')` solve your issue?

Comment: More importantly, you haven't explained what you're trying to do. What are you trying to accomplish by passing a parameter to `get`? I assumed in my previous comment that it was to filter down to certain elements, but upon review I've noticed that this was only a guess.

Comment: Your description of the [`get()`](https://api.jquery.com/get/) method seems inaccurate; what - as Tyler asks - are you trying to do? Please read the "*[mcve]*" and "*[ask]*" guidelines, and [edit] your question so that we can (better) help you.

Comment: I'm not using get ! `.get()` uses an index to return the corresponding object in the array `selection`. I need to get one object, the `selection` object that has the `:hover` attribute.

Comment: It seems what you want is a simple event handler for `mouseenter` event.

Comment: Okay, so you're not using `get()`; what are you trying to do? What's the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Just some unrelated advice, but it's pretty common to do this `var $list = $('selector');` instead of `var list = $('selector');` to indicate there is a jQuery object in the variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`.filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)  method

```js
var selection = $('.class'); //selection is an array of JQuery objects.
...
selection.filter('.some-selector').each(function() {});
```

But not sure what you try to accomplish with `:hover` as a selector. It does not exist currently.